# Where does the copied data get placed when publishing a service to ArcGIS Server

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.1

I use ArcGIS for Server 10.1. What is not clear to me is, where does server save data when I upload it to it?
I mean the case, when data in the service is not referenced, but it is inside the service definition file.

Is it saved in some folder?
Or is it saved in some geodatabase included in the server? Where?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you publish a service and its data is being copied to the server, the data is being copied into C:\arcgisserver\directories\arcgissystem\arcgisinput\%servicename% folder (or whatever folder you chose to have your server directories stored). It is a file geodatabase that is created there and it contains those datasets you have added to your map document when publishing.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Now I understand it. I could not find the arcgisinput folder on my Linux machine, but that's not that important. The main thing for me is general understanding. Thanks.

Comment: OK, I have found it. By default, the location on Linux is following: /arcgis/server/usr/directories/arcgissystem/arcgisinput/%servicename%

Comment: Great! I did not know that you are on Linux :)